# Style text with transform

Tags: html, css

I have an absolute positioned link who's text I wish to transform
to either

```
transform: rotate(315)
```

or

Get the text to arc on the inside

Here is what I have now: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpxprR)

I have tried:

- SVG path
- Libraries like `arktext.js`

**EDIT**

It seems that it has nothing to do with it being `absolute`.
It was just `315` was not a valid value.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/ ?

Comment: @halfzebra currently trying it, currently trying to vertically align the content to bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use transform, you need to specify that you are using degrees.

```
transform: rotate(315deg);
```

Updated [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYEYxR?editors=110)

Comment: There are others but degrees is usually the most common - http://www.impressivewebs.com/alternative-units-css3-rotate-transforms/ `Turns` is nice and simple though.

Answer (score 1):

Put your text inside p tags then transform that.

```
<a href="#skills" id="top-left-circle" class="panel">
    <p>Hello</p>
</a>

a > p {
    -ms-transform: rotate(315deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
    transform: rotate(315deg);
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWKWOj

Comment: I would use a `p` tag instead of a `div` tag; it's just nicer semantically.